# Problems parsing Google Data Booksearch API XML in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, xpath

I'm trying to parse some XML I've gotten from the [Google Data Booksearch API](http://code.google.com/apis/books/) and I'm having trouble trying to target a specific element. Currently my  code looks like so:

```
require 'gdata'

client = GData::Client::BookSearch.new
feed = client.get("http://books.google.com/books/feeds/volumes?q=Foundation").to_xml

books = []

feed.elements.each('entry') do |entry|
  book = {
  :title   => entry.elements['title'].text,
  :author  => entry.elements['dc:creator'].text,
  :book_id => entry.elements['dc:identifier'].text
  }

  books.push(book)
end

p books
```

and that all works fine, but I want to add a thumbnail URL to the book hash. The tag with each book's thumbnail URL looks like so:

```
<feed>
  <entry>
    ...
    <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/books/2008/thumbnail" type="image/x-unknown" href="http://bks6.books.google.com/books?id=ID5P7xbmcO8C&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_gdata"/>
    ...
  </entry>
</feed>
```

I want to grab the contents of the href attribute from this element and I'm not exactly sure how. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Ruby GData library already uses [REXML](http://germane-software.com/software/rexml/), so I think you could add something like this to your book hash (borrowing Marc's XPath):

```
:thumb_href => entry.get_elements('//link[@rel="http://schemas.google.com/books/2008/thumbnail"]')[0].attribute('href').to_s
```

I almost forgot the ".to_s", which you'll need if you want to treat it as a string. :-)

Comment: Hmm, for whatever reason that's not working, I get an error when I try to run it.

`/Users/rpowell93/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/element.rb:538:in 'xpath': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: My latest edit to the answer above should work, as I've actually _tested_ it in IRB this time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using this query, I was able to extract the href in XML Copy Editor

```
//link[@rel="http://schemas.google.com/books/2008/thumbnail"]/@href
```

You will need to open the document with Nokogiri and then run the xpath on that document, something like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://books.google.com/books/feeds/volumes?q=Foundation'))
doc.xpath('//link[@rel="http://schemas.google.com/books/2008/thumbnail"]/@href').each do |link|
    puts link.content
end
```